# Cannot load a view inside a div using Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter, I want to change only the content of page without refreshing the page. Used ajax for that but cannot load a view.

view-

```
                <div class="tb-detail">
                <a href="" class="logos">Click to change</a>
                    <form action="" method="post">
                    <div class="success_message"></div>

                        <div class="tb-detail-inner" id="general">

                                    <label>Logo</label>

                                    <input type="file" name="images">
                                    <span>Upload the logo</span>
                                    <textarea class="slogon"></textarea>
                                        <span class="help-block">Change the slogon</span>

                          </div>                                

                      <div><button>Save</button></div>

                    </form>   
                </div>
```

I want the content of div which have the class tb-detail-inner should change with the content of another view(logo). For that I have written a script which looks like this-

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var base_url = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>';


        $(".logos").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: base_url + 'index.php/panal/logos',
                dataType:'html',
                 statusCode: {
                    404: function() {
                      $(".tb-detail-inner").html('Could not contact server.');
                    },
                    500: function() {
                      $(".tb-detail-inner").html('A server-side error has occurred.');
                    }
                  },
                  error: function() {
                    $(".tb-detail-inner").html('A problem has occurred.');
                  },
                success: function(data) {
                   $(".tb-detail-inner").html(data);
                   console.log(data);
              }
            });

        });



    });



</script>
```

and Controller is-

```
<?php


class Panal extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

    }
    public function index() {
        $this->load->view('setting/logo');

    }
     public function logos() {
        $this->load->view('setting/logo');

    }
    }
```

this panel control have method logos which load logo.php view. I want to change the content with logo.php view

Comment: Is there any error that you are getting while making the ajax request? Use an error function to check and also `console.log(data)` in the success function of ajax.

Comment: you code seems fine, open the developer tools in your browser and check that your AJAX request is going to the correct path. or use console.log(data) just after receiving the response to check what is being received...

Comment: Used console.log(data),there are no error showing.

Comment: @Deepika try this `echo  $this->load->view('setting/logo',null,true);die();`  in `logos()` method

Comment: echo $this->load->view('setting/logo',null,true);die(); is not working

Comment: Is anything being shown from the ajax call i.e. "Cound not contact server" or "A server-side error occured" etc?

Answer (score 0):

try using `empty string` instead of `null` in the second parameter

```
public function logos(){
    echo $this->load->view('setting/logos', '', true);
}
```